# bluetooth on ubuntu 15.04\

Tags: bluetooth, wacom

I recently updated to ubuntu 15 from 14 and I noticed that the bluetooth (B.T.) connection is lost. I used the B.T. for plugging a bamboo tablet and it was working fine for ubuntu 14, but now the tablet is not recognized (although the wacom tablet is found by using the lsusb command and the related grub line is usbhid.quirks=0x056a:0x0319:0x40000000") and the B.T. options are dead. This means that there is not B.T. icon on the menu bar even if the option is checked, and the bluetooth ON/OFF and visibility ON/OFF buttons cannot be used (the mouse cannot move the selectors).

The outcome of is lsusb; dmesg | grep -i bluetooth; dmesg | grep -i firmware; lsmod | grep bluetooth; rfkill list all:

Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub

Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub

Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

Bus 005 Device 003: ID 045e:00db Microsoft Corp. Natural Ergonomic Keyboard 4000 V1.0

Bus 005 Device 002: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver

Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub

Bus 001 Device 003: ID 148f:3072 Ralink Technology, Corp. RT3072 Wireless Adapter

Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

Bus 004 Device 002: ID 056a:0319 Wacom Co., Ltd

Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub

[    0.024015] [Firmware Bug]: AMD-Vi: IOAPIC[0] not in IVRS table

[    0.024019] [Firmware Bug]: AMD-Vi: No southbridge IOAPIC found

[    0.206326] [Firmware Bug]: ACPI: No _BQC method, cannot determine initial brightness

[    0.210338] [Firmware Bug]: ACPI: No _BQC method, cannot determine initial brightness

[    8.355559] [Firmware Bug]: ACPI: No _BQC method, cannot determine initial brightness

[   25.738764] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00lib_request_firmware: Info - Loading firmware file 'rt2870.bin'

[   25.782857] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00lib_request_firmware: Info - Firmware detected - version: 0.29

0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

To note the wacom connection at Bus 004 Device 002 which i previously inserter in the grup file.
Any tip?

Thank you

Comment: Please edit your question to include `lsusb; dmesg | grep -i bluetooth; dmesg | grep -i firmware; lsmod | grep bluetooth; rfkill list all`

Comment: Does the results from `lsusb` change if you remove the quirk line from grub and can you boot a 14.04 Live version and see what `lsusb` was then?